# How to insert content after and before image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put pseudo class after image in html but it doesn't work. That's what I've done:

```
<img src="image.png" class="item-portfolio" alt="portfolio item">
```

CSS

```
.item-portfolio img:after{
    content: url(images/shadow.png) no-repeat; 
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 0;
}
.item-portfolio p:before{
    content: url(images/shadow.png) no-repeat;  
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    left: 6px;
    top: 0;
}
```

Is it posible to set this images after image?

Comment: Enclose within a `span`?

Comment: you mean `<span><img src="image.png" class="item-portfolio" alt="portfolio item"></span>` ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanoc/DgV78/
check this link

Comment: @user3699634: Yes and putting the before and after on the `span`. Roughly like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yw8Dm/).

Comment: Your example is good but in my files it doesn't work ;(

Comment: @user3699634: Can you post your markup also/create a fiddle so that we can see why it fails and help.

Comment: I used jquery but thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SCRIPT**

```
 $('img')
.before('<span> Before</span>')
.after('<span> After</span>');
```

Through Jquery u can insert after and Before

Answer (score 5):

`img` elements are *replaced* elements, [the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content) specifically states:

> Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of
>   :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This
>   will be defined in more detail in a future specification.

As such, such pseudo elements should not be used for `img`.

The way of counteracting this is to wrap the image within a parent element, and apply `:before/after` to that.

[**More on replaced elements from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)

> In CSS, a replaced element is an element whose representation is
>   outside the scope of CSS. These are kind of external objects whose
>   representation is independant of the CSS. Typical replaced elements
>   are `<img>`, `<object>`, `<video>` or forms element like `<textarea>`,
>   `<input>`. Some elements, like  or  are replaced elements
>   only in specific cases. Object inserted using the CSS content
>   properties are anonymous replaced elements.

Answer (score 1):

pseudo-elements do not work with img tag

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content